# power shell file not created

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

my need is that I have an interface that drops files regularly into a specific directory. I need to monitor this directory to make sure the interface is still functional. I must be notified by e-mail if there is no new file created for more than one specific time (x hours). I need a script powershell that can notify me in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some Cron Job Schedule that will send you the email by checking the status of you conditions.

Link below will help you.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649816(v=wps.630).aspx

Thanks

Comment: Link only answers aren't really answers. Links may change and this one isn't that helpful.

Comment: Tanks Muhammad, but my question is to have a script doing  my need.This is my difficulties, I can do a schedule task runnig  the scripts every hour  by example and verify if I received new files.